# Stored procedure, left join gives me duplicate rows, but I want top(1) row for each record with same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure,

```
SELECT Top(1)
    TableA.*,
        TableB.*,
        someFunction(TableA.ID),
        coalesce(TableC.someColumn, -1) As SomeColumnExample
 FROM 
    TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.IDA
    LEFT JOIN  TableC ON TableA.ID = TableC.IDA

Where TableA.ID = @ParaID
Order By TableC.DateTime Desc
```

Now I am getting results for example,

```
IDA   SomeColumn  DateAdded
1     100         2014-05-15 10:22:00
1     200         2014-05-10 12:00:00
2     300         2014-06-10 12:00:00
3     400         2014-07-10 12:00:00
```

What I want (latest date)

```
IDA   SomeColumn  DateAdded
1     200         2014-05-10 12:00:00
2     300         2014-06-10 12:00:00
3     400         2014-07-10 12:00:00
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If the other table *doesn't* have records for a given ID, the original row will still show up but the columns from TableC added by the `LEFT JOIN` will simply be null. Are you saying you want the output to have different columns in that case?

Comment: I think people are unsure of the final results you want. Please post sample data and sample results to help us help you.

Comment: Show us sample output, because as I'm reading this, you can't do a LEFT on SOME rows, and not others without some NULLS.

Comment: Still not clear. What do you want the output to be in that case?

Comment: @CustomizedName `if TableC has a record for responding IDA.` Does it means you only want Left Join if `TableC` is not null or what ?

Comment: @SurajSingh: pretty sure **he** doesn't know what he wants ATM. Let him think about it.

Comment: @AlvinThompson you are right, I wasn't knew what I was looking for, actually I was looking for coalesce(TableC.SomeColumn, -1) as Null was throwing error in dataset, you actually helped me thanks :)

Comment: Yep. Add an answer to your own question for people searching in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I was looking for something that will not give me null columns with left join, so I used,

```
coalesce(TableC.SomeColumn, -1) As SomeColumnHeHe
```

Then I came across issue where I needed to only select top 1 from left join, so i used OUTER APPLY, as shown below,

```
SELECT Top(1)
    TableA.*,
        TableB.*,
        someFunction(TableA.ID),
        coalesce(TableC.someColumn, -1) As SomeColumnExample,
        TempTable.IDA
 FROM 
    TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.IDA
    OUTER APPLY
         (SELECT TOP(1) * FROM TableC where TableC.IDA = TableA.IDA Order By DateAdded Desc )  As TempTable

Where TableA.ID = @ParaID
Order By TableC.DateTime Desc
```

Comment: Please ignore variable names as i hand written this but it worksw

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you're describing isn't a left join, it's an inner join.  Why is it you're saying it *must be* a left join?

If you only want records when there is a corresponding record in table C, then an inner join will accomplish that

EDIT:

your question seems to have significantly changed... I really have no idea what you're asking for now.  Your select statement doesn't in any way represent the sample data.