# Comparing top two rows in outer reply just for a result column but last result should keep outer applying top 1 row to result only

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a Stored procedure,

```
Declare @UserID VARCHAR(200), @URLFilter varchar(256);
SET @UserID = '298';
SET @URLFilter = 'https://myportal.toshibafirst.com/sites';

SELECT t.*
FROM(SELECT Distinct
    Problems.ID, Problems.Title, Problems.URL,
    Policies.ClientID, Policies.ID As PolicyID, Problems.CategoryID, ProblemCategories.Title As CategoryTitle,
    ProblemImply.Effect AS LatestEffect, ProblemImply.Probability AS LatestProbability, 
    ProblemImply.SolutionDate AS MovementDate, DATEDIFF(DAY, ProblemImply.SolutionDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) As MovementInDays,
    CompanyGroups.ID As GroupID, CompanyGroups.Title As GroupTitle, SolutionStartDate, SolutionStatus,  SolutionTitle,
    dbo.IsUserAdmin(@UserID, ProblemCategories.ProblemGroupID) AS IsUserAdmin,
    dbo.FunctionA(@UserID, ProblemCategories.ID) AS FunctionAOutput,
    dbo.FunctionB(@UserID, Problems.ID) AS FunctionBOutput

From ProblemCategories
INNER JOIN Policies ON Policies.ID = ProblemCategories.PolicyID
FULL OUTER JOIN Problems ON Problems.CategoryID = ProblemCategories.ID
OUTER APPLY  
        (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Problems_Imply WHERE Problems_Imply.ProblemID = Problems.ID
         AND Problems_Imply.Description <> 'Target' AND Problems_Imply.Effect > -1 AND Problems_Imply.Probability > -1
         ORDER BY Problems_Imply.SolutionDate Desc) As ProblemImply
OUTER APPLY  
        (SELECT Problems_Solutions.StartDate AS SolutionStartDate, Problems_Solutions.Status AS SolutionStatus, Problems_Solutions.GroupID, Problems_Solutions.Title AS SolutionTitle
         FROM Problems_Solutions WHERE ProblemID = Problems.ID AND Status NOT IN ('Cancelled')) As ProblemSolution
LEFT JOIN CompanyGroups ON ProblemSolution.GroupID = CompanyGroups.ID
WHERE Problems.ID IS NOT NULL AND ProblemCategories.URL LIKE '%' + @URLFilter + '%'  AND Problems.Status LIKE 'Open') t
WHERE (t.IsUserAdmin > 0 OR t.FunctionAOutput > 0 OR t.FunctionBOutput > 0) AND t.SolutionTitle IS NOT NULL
```

It gives me perfect results, but now I have to change it, I change it in a way so that in this outer apply below,

```
OUTER APPLY  
        (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Problems_Imply WHERE Problems_Imply.ProblemID = Problems.ID
         AND Problems_Imply.Description <> 'Target' AND Problems_Imply.Effect > -1 AND Problems_Imply.Probability > -1
         ORDER BY Problems_Imply.SolutionDate Desc) As ProblemImply
```

I want another result added to `t` which will be something like this,

```
@Compare = (TopFirstRow.Effect * TopFirstRow.Probability) > (TopSecondRow.Effect * TopSecondRow.Probability) 
OR it remained same or if it decreased.
```

I need to adjust this @Compare in outer APPLY, so I get it for each line. However I don't want my result to change other then getting another column @Compare.

I can think of adding another Outer Apply and call this table again and then calculate the difference but is there any better way of doing it ?

**Just to make it a bit more sense, I need to check whether Effect * Probability increased, decreased or remained same when comparing 1st top row with 2nd top row if exists**

Comment: why do you need an outer apply here? why not do a normal join?

Comment: @ughai because of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329300/stored-procedure-left-join-gives-me-duplicate-rows-but-i-want-top1-row-for-e/24330427#24330427

Comment: I don't see any condition which relates to any outer table. Is `@ID` really `someoutertable.ID` and not a parameter?. can you post the complete query so we have a better understanding

Comment: @ughai I edited my question to make it clear what I wanted

Comment: The answer provided by a-ツ should help you. Just change `Fruits.Description <> TableA.Description ` to `Fruits.ExpiryDate <> TableA.ExpiryDate` or `Fruits.PK <> TableA.PK` where PK is your primary key column

Comment: @ughai can't do that, description can be same for all rows, and if i must have to apply another outerapply, I would just select 2nd row somehow maybe, unfortunately not providing me the answer though

Comment: your sql server version is indeed 2008 or 2012 ?

Comment: it is 2008, but we may move to 2012 soon

Comment: edited my answer, i may add a sql 2012 version later if soon means really soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your APPLY has no outer references, so you can change it to a normal join, as such I would just change your query to:

```
WITH Top2Fruits AS
(   SELECT  TOP 2 
            ID, 
            Description, 
            Weight,
            Size,
            DaysLeft,
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ExpiryDate DESC)
    FROM    Fruits
    WHERE   Fruits.ID = @ID
    ORDER BY ExpiryDate DESC
)
SELECT  <columns>,
        Compare = CASE WHEN (f1.Weight * f1.Size) > (f2.Weight * f2.Size) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM    <tables>
        LEFT JOIN Top2Fruits AS f1
            ON f1.RowNum = 1
        LEFT JOIN Top2Fruits AS f2
            ON f1.RowNum = 2;
```

Now you have access to both the 1st and 2nd fruits in your derived tables f1, and f2 respectively.

---

**ADDENDUM**

Even with your outer reference you can still use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `LEFT JOIN`:

```
WITH ProblemImply AS
(
    SELECT  ProblemID,
            Effect,
            Probability,
            SolutionDate,
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() PARTITION BY ProblemID ORDER BY SolutionDate DESC)
    FROM    Problems_Imply 
    WHERE   Description <> 'Target' 
    AND     Effect > -1 
    AND     Probability > -1
), DistinctData AS
(
    SELECT  pr.ID, 
            pr.Title, 
            pr.URL,
            po.ClientID, 
            po.ID AS PolicyID, 
            pr.CategoryID, 
            pc.Title AS CategoryTitle,
            pi1.Effect AS LatestEffect, 
            pi1.Probability AS LatestProbability, 
            pi1.SolutionDate AS MovementDate,
            pi2.Effect AS PreviousEffect, 
            pi2.Probability AS PreviousProbability, 
            pi2.SolutionDate AS PreviousMovementDate,
            DATEDIFF(DAY, pi1.SolutionDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) As MovementInDays,
            cg.ID As GroupID, 
            cg.Title As GroupTitle, 
            ps.StartDate AS SolutionStartDate, 
            ps.Status AS SolutionStatus,  
            ps.Title AS SolutionTitle,
            dbo.IsUserAdmin(@UserID, pc.ProblemGroupID) AS IsUserAdmin,
            dbo.FunctionA(@UserID, pc.ID) AS FunctionAOutput,
            dbo.FunctionB(@UserID, pr.ID) AS FunctionBOutput,
            CASE SIGN((pi1.Effect * pi1.Probability) - (pi2.Effect * pi2.Probability))
                WHEN 1 THEN 'Increase'
                WHEN 0 THEN 'Static'
                WHEN -1 THEN 'Decrease'
                ELSE 'No Previous Data'
            END AS Compare
    FROM    ProblemCategories AS pc
            INNER JOIN Policies AS po
                ON po.ID = pc.PolicyID
            FULL OUTER JOIN Problems AS pr
                ON pr.CategoryID = pc.ID
            LEFT JOIN ProblemImply AS pi1
                ON pi1.ProblemID = pr.ID
                AND pi1.RowNum = 1
            LEFT JOIN ProblemImply AS pi2
                ON pi2.ProblemID = pr.ID
                AND pi2.RowNum = 2
            LEFT JOIN Problems_Solutions AS ps
                ON ps.ProblemID = pr.ID
                AND ps.Status NOT IN ('Cancelled')
            LEFT JOIN CompanyGroups AS cg
                ON ps.GroupID = cg.ID
    WHERE   pr.ID IS NOT NULL 
    AND     pc.URL LIKE '%' + @URLFilter + '%'  
    AND     pr.Status LIKE 'Open'
) t
SELECT  *
FROM    DistinctData AS t
WHERE   (t.IsUserAdmin > 0 OR t.FunctionAOutput > 0 OR t.FunctionBOutput > 0) 
AND     t.SolutionTitle IS NOT NULL;
```

*I have used aliases to make the query a bit more legible, but there is a chance I may have got a couple wrong, sorry about that, but it is difficult with no data to test with :)*

Comment: a top whatever makes no sense without a order by and since you select a specific rownum when doing the left join, you don't need it anyway. and you'll have to do a `partition by friuts.ID` when creating the rownum in order to get one (or 2) row per fruit.

Comment: Spotted the missing order by and corrected it. It does not mention in the question that it needs to be TOP 1 per fruits.ID, in fact, as stated, the APPLY has no outer references so there is no partitioning.

Comment: I am really sorry for confusion but I added @ID by mistake, I added full stored procedure now

Comment: @GarethD Thanks for your edit, I implemented it, but there's something missing in your edit, I am using Problems_Imply.ProblemID = Problems.ID with outer apply both of them are not implemented here, so I am not getting desired result, maybe I didn't understood it properly, I only want specific id records from here Problems_Imply

Comment: That same filter is in the JOIN predicate (`ON pi1.ProblemID = pr.ID`)

Comment: Your answer helped me getting my final answer, I ended up creating a separate function which I may add later on, but I will accept your answer as it helped me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

there are generally 2 versions, outer apply and join. i prefere outer apply when the result doesn't change the rowcount.

and you can select the top 2 rows in different ways:

```
with cte as (
  select *
       , rn = row_number() over ( partition by id order by somedate) 
  from y    
) 
select * 
  from x 
  left join cte  on x.id=cte.id
  left join cte cte2 on cte.id=cte2.id and cte.rn=1 and cte2.rn=2

select * 
  from x 
  outer apply (
    select top 1 * 
    from y 
    where x.id=y.id 
    order by somedate
  ) cte
  outer apply (
    select top 1 * 
    from y 
    where x.id=y.id and y.somedate>cte.somedate
    order by somedate
  ) cte2
```

both have the same problem, the result isn't predictable and likely not correct if somedate (or whatever column(s) you use to sort it) isn't unique per id

and the execution plan will differ. 'outer apply`will likely result in nested loops, joins may get mixed up with other joins in your query and could be executed too early ( with too many ids). both queries hit the cte twice.

since you have a rather complicated query already and some difficulties to order the rows predictable and you are within a stored procedure, i'd go for table variable. i often found my stored proc run way faster if i part huge queries into smaller pieces and searching for errors has been way easier too.

```
declare  cte as table 
   ( id int not null
   , rn int not null 
   , primary key (id,rn)
   , data something 
   , ...
   );

declare rows as table 
   ( id int not null
   , data something 
   , ...
   );

insert into @rows (...)
select * from your rather_large_query;

with cte as (
  select *
       , rn = row_number() over ( partition by id order by somedate) 
  from y    
) 
insert into @cte ( id, rn, data, ...)
select * 
  from cte 
  where rn in (1,2) and id in (select id from @rows);

select * 
  from @rows x
  left join @cte cte  on x.id=cte.id
  left join @cte cte2 on cte.id=cte2.id and cte.rn=1 and cte2.rn=2
```

hope it helps

Comment: Nice. But the `AND Fruits.Description <> TableA.Description` should probably be `AND Fruits.ID <> TableA.ID`

Comment: @ypercube  na, it shouldn't ... `WHERE Fruits.ID = @ID` selects only one id which isn't a primary key (or so it seams)

Comment: Yes, my bad. It should be `AND Fruits.PK <> TableA.PK`, whatever the primary key is.`

Comment: I am really sorry for confusion but I added @ID by mistake, I added full stored procedure now

Comment: @Aツ thanks but fruits.description is not something I can depend on, it can be same for all rows

Comment: In the very first query, the `left join cte2 on` should be `left join cte cte2 on`